# How to change the resolution on screen at Startup in Fedora?

Tags: fedora, startup, display, radeon, amd-graphics

I have just installed Fedora 22 and am new to the Linux environment. My problem is this, at startup the GPU doesn't seem to auto detect the resolution of my monitor.

```
xrandr --newmode "1440x900_60.00"  106.50  1440 1528 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DVI-1 "1440x900_60.00"
xrandr --output DVI-1 --mode "1440x900_60.00"
```

So far I was doing this to allow me to change the resolution on my monitor however it is a temporary solution. Is there a way that allows me to run those commands at startup? I believe I had already tried to use "rcon" yesterday but that didn't work.

Comment: What video card? And what monitor, for that matter? This is almost certainly due to a bug (and a [bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/enter_bug.cgi?format=guided&product=Fedora) would be appreciated).

Comment: You may also want to try Fedora 23 — out tomorrow! — to see if it fixes this problem.

Answer (score -2):

Put your commands in an `.xinitrc` file in your home directory. The last one should actually be enough.

Comment: Am I meant to create it if it's not there? (Just checking... I'm new to this) if I am can I just do `touch xinitrc` ?

Comment: I'm assuming I also have to use `#!/bin/bash ` at the start, don't I?

Comment: no, .xinitrc gets read when your user's X session starts. Don't forget the `.`. The file should be named `.xinitrc` as opposed to `xinitrc`. Create the file, if it is not already there.

Comment: right so I dont need to use `#!/bin/bash` at the start... as that didn't work, yes?

Comment: Tried, no success :/

Comment: This might give you some conclusion:
[link](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/fedora-35/xession-script-containig-xrandr-commands-not-taking-effect-4175414245/)

Comment: Ye... that lead me no where :/